# Firebase google authentication in Chrome Extension - Error getting credential

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I'm working on updating a chrome extension to MV3, and therefore I can't use the firebase UI to login any more.  What I trying to do is use chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow, get the token, create the credential, and sign in with firebase.
Here's what I have:

```
function launchGoogleAuthFlow(interactive) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('launching webauthflow')
    const manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
    const clientId = encodeURIComponent(manifest.oauth2.client_id);
    const scopes = encodeURIComponent(manifest.oauth2.scopes.join(' '));

let redirectUri = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL();
let nonce = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)

const authUrl = new URL('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth');

  authUrl.searchParams.set('client_id', clientId);
  authUrl.searchParams.set('response_type', 'id_token');
  authUrl.searchParams.set('redirect_uri', redirectUri);
  // Add the OpenID scope. Scopes allow you to access the user’s information.
  authUrl.searchParams.set('scope', 'openid profile email');
  authUrl.searchParams.set('nonce', nonce);
  // Show the consent screen after login.
  authUrl.searchParams.set('prompt', 'consent');


    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
      {
        'url': authUrl.href,
        'interactive': interactive
      },
      (redirectedTo) => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
          resolve(null)
        }
        else {
          let idToken = redirectedTo.substring(redirectedTo.indexOf('id_token=') + 9)
          idToken = idToken.substring(0, idToken.indexOf('&'))
          resolve(idToken)
        }
      }
    )
  })
}

launchGoogleAuthFlow(true).then((token)=>{
        if (token) {
          console.log('token:' + token);
          const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, token);
          console.log(credential);
          signInWithCredential(auth, credential).then((result) => {
            showMain();
      document.getElementById('loggedInAs').textContent = result.email;

              console.log("Success!!!")
              console.log(result)
          }).catch((error) => {
              // You can handle errors here
              console.log(error)
          });
      } else {
          console.error('The OAuth token was null');
      }
      }); 
      console.log('finished authflow');
  }
```

I'm getting prompted to sign in with my google credentials, then in the console I get Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
and then the a log from SignInWithCredentials

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Unsuccessful check authorization response from Google: {
  "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
 (auth/invalid-credential).
    at _errorWithCustomMessage (index-6bd8d405.js:453:1)
    at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (index-6bd8d405.js:973:1)
    at async _performSignInRequest (index-6bd8d405.js:988:1)
    at async _signInWithCredential (index-6bd8d405.js:4721:1)
```

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions on this?

Comment: I have the same issue, same error. Haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: It's looking like Edge just isn't going to be able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `response_type` you are requesting an `id_token`:

```js
authUrl.searchParams.set('response_type', 'id_token');
```

So your `launchGoogleAuthFlow` returns an `id_token` and that's it what you must give to `GoogleAuthProvider.credential`. This method expects an a `id_token` as the first parameter and an a `access_token` as the second parameter.

So all you have to do is change from:

```js
const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, token);
```

to:

```js
const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(token);
```

Everything should works fine.

---

If you may want the `access_token` you must request `response_type=token` and remove `nonce`. Finally you'll need to extract the returned `access_token` from response URL (your `redirectedTo` variable) as you did with `id_token`.

---

PS: In your code I also noticed that you got scopes from manifest but did not use them while requesting the token.